# Add partial data from dictionary to a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame df with `columns = [A, B, C, D, E, F, G]`. Currently all values are `np.nan`except column F and G which contain "Country" "City" respectively. 
I have a dictionary such that dictionary = `{A: 1, B: 3, D: 4}`.

I want to add values from dictionary to dataframe such that the values in column `A, B, D` is `1, 3, 4` respectively while everything else remains what it was before adding the dictionary.

For example:

before addition
df:

### A   B   C   D   E     F         G

Nan Nan Nan Nan Nan "Country" "City"

After:

### A   B   C   D   E     F         G

1  3   Nan  4  Nan "Country" "City"

Comment: does the df has 1 row?

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
# empty df:
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=list('ABCDE'))

# append
df.append(pd.Series(d), ignore_index=True)
```

Output:

```
     A    B   C    D   E
0  1.0  2.0 NaN  4.0 NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

Try update:

```
df =pd.DataFrame(columns = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'])
df.loc[0]=np.nan
```

---

```
     A    B    C    D    E
0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

---

```
d={'A': 1, 'B': 3, 'D': 4}
df.update(pd.Series(d).to_frame().T)
print(df)
```

---

```
   A  B    C  D    E
0  1  3  NaN  4  NaN
```